# OS Commerce not displaying products with zero quantity from one category

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

A recent issue our online store ran into using os commerce, was that when a product went to zero quantity it goes to out of stock, which is great. However in my situation, the previously web developer/admin *did not* actually do inventory on these products. Which I'm slowly fixing, however this web store contains a lot of products. I'm trying to develop a quicker method to this madness. So I constructed a small script to display any products with a quantity that's equal or lesser to '1'.

```
$dig_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
    while($products = mysql_fetch_array($dig_products))
    {
        if($products['products_quantity'] <= 1)
        {
            echo $products['products_id'] . '- (' . $products['products_quantity'] . ')<br>';
        }
    }
```

The downfall is that it also displays products in the 'Discountinued' category, which is a lot of results. I'm trying to narrow those products that do not fall into that category. Now the products table doesn't hold any information about categories and that information is held in 'products_to_categories' table. I'm thinking of a INNER JOIN of the two databases, but I'm not sure how to display the results. The 'Discontinued' category value is '185', so I'm trying to display products that do not fall in that '185' category. Hope this makes sense, it's been a long day ;) Thank you!

EDIT: This something that I'm working on, it wont work. But concept of what I'm trying to do.

```
$dig_products = mysql_query("SELECT products.products_id, products.products_model, products.products_quantity, products_to_category.categoies_id FROM products LEFT JOIN products_to_categories ON products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id WHERE (products.products_quantity <= 1) AND (products_to_categories.categories_id != 185)") or die(mysql_error());
    while($products = mysql_fetch_array($dig_products))
    {

        echo $products['products_id'] . '- <strong>' . $products['products_model'] . ' </strong> (' . $products['products_quantity'] . ')<br>';

    }
```

Comment: You REALLY should put your filtering into the sql where clause: `where (products_quantity <= 1) AND (product_category = 185)`.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering about that, rather than placing an if statement.